# How to prepare Python Selenium project to be used on client's machine?

Tags: python, selenium

I've recently started freelance python programming, and was hired to write a script that scraped certain info online (nothing nefarious, just checking how often keywords appear in search results).

I wrote this script with Selenium, and now that it's done, I'm not quite sure how to prepare it to run on the client's machine.

Selenium requires a path to your chromedriver file. Am I just going to have to compile the py file as an exe and accept the path to his chromedriver as an argument, then show him how to download chromedriver and how to write the path?

EDIT: Just actually had a thought while typing this out. Would it work if I sent the client a folder including a chromedriver.exe inside of said folder, so the path was always consistent?

Comment: Deliver it in a zipfile with preset folders and set the relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using this Docker image for all my python/selenium code.
https://github.com/cloudbees/java-build-tools-dockerfile.git
It has everything you need and more installed for selenium testing with python. It is built by the Jenkins team but you can run it locally.

You could add this to launch your script automatically. Then build your Dockerfile.

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py" ]

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1)**  Deliver a Docker image if customer not to watch the browser during running and they can setup Docker environment. The Docker image should includes following items:

1. Python
2. Dependencies for running your script, like selenium
3. Headless chrome browser and compatible chrome webdriver binary
4. Your script, put them in github and
   fetch them when start docker container, so that customer can always get
   your latest code

This approach's benefit:

1. You only need to focus on scripts like bug fix and improvement after delivery
2. Customer only need to execute same docker command

**Option 2)** Deliver a Shell script to do most staff automatically. It should accomplish following items:

1. Install Python (Or leave it for customer to complete)
2. Install Selenium library and others needed
3. Install latest chrome webdriver binary (which is compatible backward)
4. Fetch your script from code repo like github, or simply deliver as packaged folder
5. Run your script.

**Option 3)** Deliver your script and an user guide, customer have to do many staff by self. You can supply a config file along with your script for customer to specify the chrome driver binary path after they download.  Your script read the path from this file, better than enter it in cmd line every time.

Comment: Docker Image seems to be the best option here, I'm not all that familiar with working with Docker though. Any recommendations for a guide that covers taking a python program and turning it into a functioning Docker image?